# What's difference between EveryJob and IntervalJob in rufus-scheduler gem?

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I think EveryJob with option `overlap: false` is IntervalJob. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

From the documentation:

> Whereas "every" jobs are like "every 10 minutes, do this", interval jobs are like "do that, then wait for 10 minutes, then do that again, and so on"

And about `overlap: false`:

> Since, by default, jobs are triggered in their own new thread, job instances might overlap. For example, a job that takes 10 minutes and is scheduled every 7 minutes will have overlaps.
>
> To prevent overlap, one can set :overlap => false. Such a job will not trigger if one of its instance is already running.
>
> The :overlap option is considered after the :mutex option when the scheduler is reviewing jobs for triggering.

With `IntervalJob`, the time delta is between the last trigger end and the next trigger start point.
With `EveryJob`, the time delta is between the trigger start points.

If an `EveryJob` has `overlap: false`, it will not trigger while a trigger "session" is still going on.

https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#rufus-scheduler